# Selenium close alert in whatsapp bot

Tags: selenium, whatsapp

There is a bot that sends a message to numbers from a text file, but after switching to another person, there is an alert that needs to be confirmed.

However, it occurs when you open the next chat, and the alert processing goes the next line, but the code does not move further because it is waiting for the page to open. And I don't understand how to process these two cases at the same time

code:

```
      def acceptAlert(driver):
    try:
        wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        Alert = wait3.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
        if Alert is not None:
            driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()
    except:
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=7' +
                   str(e[1:]) + '&amp;test=sdfsdf')
        time.sleep(5)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\Marsel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\chromedriver.exe')
test = open('base.txt', 'r')
lines = test.readlines()

i = 0

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + str(lines[i]) + '&amp;test=sdfsdf')
time.sleep(15)

s = lines[i]
s = re.sub(r"[()'+']", "", s)
e = s.replace('-', '')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=7' +
            str(e[1:]) + '&amp;test=sdfsdf')
time.sleep(5)

while i < len(lines):        

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys('привет')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    s = lines[i]
    s = re.sub(r"[()'+']", "", s)
    i += 1

    acceptAlert(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split them into separate functions and add try catch blocks.

```
def acceptAlert(driver):
    try:
        wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        Alert = wait3.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
        if Alert is not None:
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
    except:
        print('No alert found')
```

And then call this method inside your code loop. So when there is no alert, it will wait for 10 seconds and still continue execution even if there is no alert.

Comment: thanks, but it's not solve the problem. When i try to catch alert it is doens't appear and then message send to the same contact(don't switch to another)

Comment: For that you should put this on a for loop. Get all numbers once and add them in a list and then call driver.get under a loop.

Comment: i added full code and i think do all things that you tell